# How to do INSERT INTO updated data from another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have a new table (called "NewTable") which is created with the data from 2 tables (t1 and t2).  I am trying to INSERT any new data in t1 and t2 INTO "NewTable".  Please see the example below.

NewTable:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
```

t1:

```
id | col1 | col2 | col5 | col6 |
```

t2:

```
id | col3 | col4 | col7 | col8 |
```

my script is:

```
INSERT NewTable (id, col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT t1.d1, col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM NewTable left join t1 on NewTable.id = t1.id left join t2 on t1.id=t2.id
WHERE t1.id is NULL;
```

I got this error message

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'New Table'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

I feel like my script is off. Should I use right join instead of left join or should I put "WHERE NewTable is NULL" instead?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Why do you need to duplicate data into New Table? Why do you think SQL is wrong - what happens? Did you use Access query designer to build?

Comment: I have updated my question. sorry about the confusion

Comment: Tag the question with the database that you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert into `NewTable` rows from `t1` and `t2` with the same `id` that don't already exist in `NewTable` then you must join with an `INNER` join `t1` and `t2`, then `LEFT` join `NewTable` and return the non matching rows:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable (id, col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT t1.id, t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col3, t2.col4
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
LEFT JOIN NewTable ON NewTable.id = t1.id
WHERE NewTable.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  I will review the answer as a practice!